# Python Speechrecognition Error Bad Request

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, http-error, bad-request

Yesterday my code was working fine. Today I woke up and started getting Bad Request errors even though I had not made any changes to the code: Here it is down below:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

    # locate audio file                                                         
AUDIO_FILE = "C:/Users/Nahuel/Transcribe_bot/noam_transcript.wav"

    # use the audio file as the audio source                                        
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file                  
        transcription = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("Transcription: " + transcription)

    # Every ten words, start the text on a new line.
paragraph = transcription
a = paragraph.split()
transcript = ""
for i in range(0, len(a), 10):
    transcript += ' '.join(a[i:i+10]) + '\n'

x = transcript        
    # Save transcription as txt file on computer.
txt_filepath = 'C:/Users/Nahuel/Transcribe_bot/'
txt_filename = 'initial_transcript'
complete_name = os.path.join(txt_filepath, txt_filename + ".txt") 
text_file = open(complete_name, 'w')
text_file.write(x)
text_file.close()
```

I tried running the script on another computer (making sure to setup and install the proper libraries and dependencies), didn't work. I tried using a VPN to change my ip address thinking maybe that will do something, didn't work. And in the middle of the week I had switched ISP's, the code worked with the old internet service and the new internet service, so I think that rules out any router issues. I don't know what else it could be. All of a sudden I'm getting Bad Request after Bad request whenever I run the code.

[image]

I'm pulling my hair out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this program exactly do? Try to add or remove some pieces of the program. Simplify and try to debug it that way. As you build on, see what parts might not be working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have been doing that but seeing as my code was working and then one day suddenly stopped, I have no choice to assume that it is not coming from my end but probably googles end. "r.recognize_google(audio)" does all the heavy lifting, without it, this whole script has no purpose.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with my speech recognition programs and I use google so it might be on your end. I don't think its a syntax error but more of a bad request. Did you upgrade python when you ran it again?